# Firestore Distributed counters billing cost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Distributed counters with 10 shards, now if I want know the Total of the counter I'll do a valueChanges or a snaphotChanges ad I have 10 reads, but if in real-time someone else update 1 shard...
for the new Total in real-time I have one read more or I have to repeat the 10 reads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is listening to a query that matches 10 documents, the listener will first cost 10 reads to read all those documents, then 1 additional read each time any of those documents changes.

It will **not** cost 10 reads every time your listener is invoked in response to a change of 1 document.  The cost of a read is only incurred when a document actually changes. The other unchanged documents are reused from memory used by the client SDK.

Comment: I use @angular/fire snapshotChanges and the first time I query the shards collection the result is 10 added doc, I change one value of shard from console, and the result is 1 modified 9 added, but in console i read form the 9 added docs, 
payload.doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot >
metadata: SnapshotMetadata >
fromCache:false
is it congruent?

Comment: Well, I can't see what you're seeing, so I don't know.